# when click on the option add inputs with option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
<script>
function run() {
document.getElementById("ip").value= document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
}
</script>


<script>
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
rowNum ++;
var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'"><span class="lb">Ip Address:</span><input id="ip" type="text" name="ip[]" size="4" value="'+frm.add_ip.value+'" required placeholder="192.168.0.1:80" class="form-control wid2" />  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');" class="remove" style=" width:9%;"></p>';
jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
frm.add_ip.value = '';

}

function removeRow(rnum) {
jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myformp">
<form method="get" class="myformp2" id="ipForm">
<div id="itemRows">
<span class="lb">Ip Address:</span><input class="form-control wid2 " type="text" name="add_ip" size="4" required placeholder="192.168.0.1:80" title="ip address" id="ip"/>   <input  type="button" value="+" class="add" style=" width:9%;" />

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default mybtn2">save</button>
<div class="clear"></div>
<select id="Ultra" onchange="run()">  <!--Call run() function-->
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="0">Select</option>
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="8">text1</option>
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="5">text2</option>
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="4">text3</option>     
</select>

</form>
</div>
```

i want when click on option input add and option value replace with input value but when click on the option more than one it dont replace and i must click on another option then click it can work!

Comment: First thing `ID` should be unique. In your code `id="ip"` is repeating.

Comment: why you want to handle double click specifically. Also even if you try to double click on select box's option; the option will get selected on first click only and it will get closed.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai when i use getelementbyclassname it dosen't work!i don't know why!

Comment: @vijayP i want when click on option input add and option value replace with input value but when click on the option more than one it dosnt work!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of the newly created input to `frm.add_ip.valuе` which is the value of the input, not the select.

Since it's in a form you're already using, you can access the select (and it's value) using

```
form.Ultra.value
```

which gives you the actual value (0,8,5,4), or you can access it via jquery with

```
$("#Ultra").val()
```

which gives you the same thing.

That said, you're generating all the other text-boxes with the same id of `ip`. Since you already give specific id's to the paragraph tags, you should use the exact approach with the text-boxes as well.

```js
<script>
function run() {
document.getElementById("ip").value= document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
}
</script>


<script>
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
rowNum ++;
var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'"><span class="lb">Ip Address:</span><input id="ip" type="text" name="ip[]" size="4" value="'+$("#Ultra").val()+'" required placeholder="192.168.0.1:80" class="form-control wid2" />  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');" class="remove" style=" width:9%;"></p>';
jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
frm.add_ip.value = '';

}

function removeRow(rnum) {
jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myformp">
<form method="get" class="myformp2" id="ipForm">
<div id="itemRows">
<span class="lb">Ip Address:</span><input class="form-control wid2 " type="text" name="add_ip" size="4" required placeholder="192.168.0.1:80" title="ip address" id="ip"/>   <input  type="button" value="+" class="add" style=" width:9%;" />

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default mybtn2">save</button>
<div class="clear"></div>
<select id="Ultra" onchange="run()">  <!--Call run() function-->
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="0">Select</option>
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="8">text1</option>
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="5">text2</option>
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="4">text3</option>     
</select>

</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `addRow` and `run` methods and add this event handler. You don't need to handle click on option separately, `onchange` on select is enough. You are not using the values of options anyways.

```
$( "#Ultra" ).change( function(){

    $( "#ip" ).val( $( this ).val() );
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'"><span class="lb">Ip Address:</span><input id="ip" type="text" name="ip[]" size="4" value="'+frm.add_ip.value+'" required placeholder="192.168.0.1:80" class="form-control wid2" />  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');" class="remove" style=" width:9%;"></p>';
    $( '#itemRows' ).append(row);

} );
```

Comment: i want when click on option input add and option value replace with input value but when click on the option more than one it dosnt work!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function run() {
    document.getElementById("ip").value = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
}

var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum' + rowNum + '"><span class="lb">Ip Address:</span><input id="ip" type="text" name="ip[]" size="4" value="' + frm.add_ip.value + '" required placeholder="192.168.0.1:80" class="form-control wid2" />  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow(' + rowNum + ');" class="remove" style=" width:9%;"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_ip.value = '';

}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myformp">
<form method="get" class="myformp2" id="ipForm">
<div id="itemRows">
<span class="lb">Ip Address:</span><input class="form-control wid2 " type="text" name="add_ip" size="4" required placeholder="192.168.0.1:80" title="ip address" id="ip"/>   <input  type="button" value="+" class="add" style=" width:9%;" />

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default mybtn2">save</button>
<div class="clear"></div>
<select id="Ultra" onchange="run()">  <!--Call run() function-->
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="0">Select</option>
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="8">text1</option>
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="5">text2</option>
     <option onclick="addRow(this.form);"value="4">text3</option>     
</select>

</form>
</div>
```

Some thing wrong !